# How to fix risk table miscalculation in Kaplan Meier plot in R

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis, medical

The following is a dataframe with a unique record_ID for each of 6 participants. I want to plot a survival analysis with relapse the event of interest and a time-dependent covariate of "exposure" to a drug dose (a numerical variable) over interval tstart to tstop.
The largest tstop for each participant is either a relapse of their disease (if event = 1) or last follow-up/time of censoring (if event = 0).

| record_id | event | tstart | tstop | exposure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 10 | 169 |
| 1 | 0 | 10 | 17 | 127 |
| 1 | 0 | 17 | 24 | 85 |
| 1 | 0 | 24 | 31 | 42 |
| 1 | 1 | 31 | 1861 | 0 |
| 37 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 37 | 0 | 10 | 13 | 50 |
| 37 | 0 | 13 | 15 | 38 |
| 37 | 0 | 15 | 18 | 25 |
| 37 | 0 | 18 | 21 | 13 |
| 37 | 1 | 21 | 24 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 6 | 36 | 136 |
| 38 | 0 | 36 | 50 | 68 |
| 38 | 0 | 50 | 147 | 45 |
| 38 | 0 | 147 | 238 | 34 |
| 38 | 0 | 238 | 3687 | 0 |
| 7625-8 | 1 | 0 | 2557 | 0 |
| 7625-9 | 0 | 0 | 14 | 0 |
| 7625-9 | 0 | 14 | 32 | 75 |
| 7625-9 | 0 | 32 | 46 | 50 |
| 7625-9 | 0 | 46 | 62 | 25 |
| 7625-9 | 1 | 62 | 63 | 23 |
| 7625-11 | 1 | 0 | 20 | 0 |

I would like to perform a Kaplan Meier-type plot for time to event, stratified by "Exposure" (one line for patients above 12.5mg at a given point in time and another line for those below).

I have tried this code:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit_c <- coxph(Surv(tstart,tstop,event) ~ strata(exposure > 12.4),
                 data = df_final)

ggsurv_12.5<-ggsurvplot(survfit(fit_c), data = df_final, 
                        xlab = "Time (days)", ylab = "Relapse freedom",
                        xlim=c(0,350),break.time.by=25,
                        risk.table = TRUE)
```

The lines look plausible, but the Risk Table tells me that at time point zero there are 6 participants on exposure <12.4 and 2 above 12.4 but there are only 6 unique IDs (6 participants) in the whole table and they are all <12.4 at time point zero. I have also tried this with many more and less patient IDs to try and identify the problem, but to no avail as yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the onset of symptoms as t=0 where no patients were on treatment (as they hadn’t even been diagnosed yet) which means that one level of the covariate had 0 members which is nonsense and R was imputing data (from somewhere!) to fill in the gap - although I'm still not sure where it was getting the number at risk in the covariate strata with no members(???).

"A characteristic of the Simon and Makuch method should be mentioned here. The number of subjects at risk is usually small in at least one level of the covariate in the early time points, so Simon and Makuch suggest selecting a starting time point after the study’s time 0 for graphical presentation. This time point would be selected to assure an adequate number of subjects at risk in each level of the covariate and would depend upon the distribution of events.”
*Schultz, L. R., Peterson, E. L. & Breslau, N. Graphing survival curve estimates for time‐dependent covariates. Int. J. Method. Psychiat. Res. 11, 68–74 (2002).

A usual/reasonable approach seems to be setting a “landmark”** time where the cohort numbers are better balanced. The most commonly chosen landmark time from my reading is the median time of commencement of response/therapy which for my cohort is day 12.
**Anderson, J. R., Cain, K. C. & Gelber, R. D. Analysis of survival by tumor response. J. Clin. Oncol. 1, 710–719 (1983).

When making the median commencement of therapy (day 12) equal Day 0, everything, including the risk table makes sense!